# Как запускать Python на других компьютерах

Tags: python-3.x

Очень нравится Python, начал изучать и поражаюсь его простоте.

Я пишу телеграмм бота, хочу его запустить на постоянной основе на сервере Windows 2012. Мне необходимо установить Python на этот сервер и еще скачать всю кучу библиотек, которую я использовал? Есть какой-нибудь иной способ?

И как быть, если у меня будет к примеру запущен Бот и плюс пару других программ, одна из которых к примеру сканирует сеть и записывает все в базу, то есть как мне запустить одновременно несколько разных приложений на сервере?

Comment: Это вы ещё `go` не пробовали ) А про сервер, заодно начните изучать linux подобные, возможно тоже приятно удивят простотой установки кучи библиотек.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian pip и на винде есть, бинарные колеса уже есть для подавляющего большинства популярных библиотек.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добрый день, попробуйте изучить возможности виртуализации и контейнеров. Идея в том, что вы можете настроить среду один раз и далее передавать контейнер в другие системы . Посмотрите такие технологии как vagrant и docker .

Альтернативным способом является создание рецепта по настройке среды для ваших нужд, так, что вы передаете на сервер только этот рецепт, а обязанности по конфигурации и установке берут на себя такие технологии как chef или puppet.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!

Уточните условия задачи.
Вообще лучший вариант - изучить Линукс. В нем эта задача решается на раз-два. Можно установить Линукс на сервер с Windows. Для этого понадобится использовать виртуализацию. Из того, что приходит в голову - virtualbox и hyper-v. Virtualbox больше подходит для настольного применения - отладка, разработка, всякие эксперименты. В принципе, для серверов его тоже можно применить, но не оптимально. Для серверного применения лучше подходит hyper-v. Пугаться не надо - это не так уж сложно.

Для запуска программы как службы под Windows есть возможность использовать утилиту srv2any, которая позволяет службу сделать из любой программы.

Сам windows сервер поддерживает многозадачность. С этим проблем нет. Костыльным решением является подключение к серверу по teamviewer и запуск программы в сеансе на физическом рабочем столе или можно запускать программу в RDP-сессии ( а потом ее не закрывать ), но эти варианты подходят для каких-то самых простых применений. И для обеспечения бесперебойной работы сервиса рекомендую его изначально грамотно проектировать

Comment: Для того чтобы юзать программы на питоне на винде нужно поставить линукс. Вся суть фитона.